# Continuous Markov chain description

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose a cell can be in two types: type I or type II. A cell of type I can become a cell of type II after a time that is distributed exponentially with parameter $a$ and a cell of type II can become *two* cells of type I after a time that is distributed exponentially with parameter $b$.

> How can I describe the population of the cells as a continuous Markov chain and what are the residence times and the transition probabilities?

What I know:
I find it very difficult to describe the population as you have to take account of both the number of I-cells and the number of II-cells.
Further I know that a transition rate matrix G is given by
$   g_{ij} = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       v_ip_{ij} & : i \neq j\\
       -v_i & : i=j
     \end{array}
   \right.$

where the residence time in state $i$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $v_i$ and $p_{ij}$ are the transition probabilities.

Comment: Each state will stay for an exponential time, and the probability of moving to another state after the transition happens is $p_{ij}$. You can't, however, use $G$ for long periods. You usually work with its derivative.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff Could you maybe help me with modelling the Markov process?

Comment: "you have to take account of both the number of I-cells and the number of II-cells." Exactly. So let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ denote the number of I-cells and the number of II-cells at time $t$, can you describe the evolution of $(X_t,Y_t)$? This will be a Markov process with a rather simple generator...

Comment: @Did I think that $(X_t,Y_t)$ transitions to $(X_t-1,Y_t+1)$ with intensity $a$ and to $(X_t+2,Y_t-1)$ with intensity $b$. But what is the generator?

Comment: This is correct, hence $g_{(x,y),(x-1,y+1)}=a$ for every $x\geqslant1$, $g_{(x,y),(x+2,y-1)}=b$ for every $y\geqslant1$, $g_{(x,y),(x,y)}=-a-b$ for every $x,y\geqslant1$, and $g_{(x,y),(u,v)}=0$ for every $x,y\geqslant1$ for the other couples $(u,v)$. This is your generator.